# How to do INSERT requiring a combination of field from another table + static values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2016 table (say "AnimalDependencies") with four columns:

```
- auto generated PKID
- AnimalID (This is a foreign key from the "Animals" table)
- Field1
- Field2
```

I need to hydrate this table with a bunch of INSERT statements. The problem is that Field1 and Field2 require static values while I would like to extract AnimalID from "Animals", something like:

```
INSERT INTO [AnimalDependencies] (AnimalID, Field1, Field2) VALUES(SELECT [Id] FROM [Animals] WHERE Name = 'Cow', 'Blah1', 'Blah2')
```

Obviously the above does not work. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [AnimalDependencies] (AnimalID, Field1, Field2) 
SELECT [Id], 'Blah1', 'Blah2' FROM [Animals] WHERE Name = 'Cow'
```